# Cannot resolve symbol FirebaseVisionTextDetector

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I get `Cannot resolve symbol FirebaseVisionTextDetector` error when I put in my module:

```
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.text.FirebaseVisionTextDetector;
```

I can't understand why because in `gradle` I have the correct implementation:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:18.0.1'
```

**SOLVED**

I have solved by downgrading to `16.0.0`. Still don't know the reason why.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:16.0.0'
```

Comment: Try to 'invalidate cache and restart', then rebuild the project (will sync automatically)

Comment: @J-me thanks. I have tried but nothing has changed.

Comment: I'm sorry but then I'm not quite sure what's the problem since I don't know what steps you've taken yet.

Please try [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-firebase-ml-kit-for-android--cms-31305) guide, it might help you.

Comment: @J-me thanks. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Downgrade is not really a solution. There are many [bug fixes and upgrades](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases) which you should ship with your app.

> `FirebaseVisionTextDetector` class was removed in
>   **[firebase-ml-vision:17.0.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-ml-vision/17.0.0)** , it was last available in **[firebase-ml-vision:16.0.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-ml-vision/16.0.0)** they have changed it to `FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer`.

There are **not much difference** between both classes. So **go ahead** and do changes.

**Changes to make:**

Before (v-16.0.0):

```
FirebaseVisionTextDetector
FirebaseVisionTextDetector.detectInImage(image)
List<FirebaseVisionText.Block> resultsBlocks = results.getBlocks();
for (FirebaseVisionText.Block block : resultsBlocks) {
            for (FirebaseVisionText.Line line : block.getLines()) {
                //...
            }
        }
```

After (v-18.0.1):

```
FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer
FirebaseVisionTextDetector.processImage(image)
List<FirebaseVisionText.TextBlock> blocks = results.getTextBlocks();
    for (FirebaseVisionText.TextBlock block : blocks) {
         // ...
        }
    }
```

You can clone [Official ML kit sample project](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit) to see complete code implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Please check [link for list of class and interface](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/ml/vision/text/package-summary)  which ML kit provide in **vision.text package**. so I guess you need to take help from `FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer` class.

**Here is the [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/recognize-text) how you can use 'FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer' class**.